# Dapper for NET Core: Insert into a table and return id of inserted row

Tags: asp.net-core, dapper

I have the following method in my repository. As of now, i believe the int returned is simply one indicating whether or not the operation was successful. I want the int to be the id (which is the single column of the table) to be returned after a successful execution. How do i accomplish this?

```
    public async Task<int> AddNewGroup()
    {
        using(_connection)
        {
            _connection.Open();
            var id = await _connection.ExecuteAsync("INSERT INTO groups").Single();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can run a query which has 2 parts, first is your **INSERT** part and second is a **SELECT** part. In the SELECT part, you can return(select) whatever column value you want.

For example, If your group table has a primary key column called `GroupId` and you have set that column for Identity value generation(automatic value generation), you can call the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the generated value.

We will use the `QueryAsync` method.

```
public async Task<int> AddNewGroup()
{
   using(_connection)
   {
      _connection.Open();
      var q = @"INSERT INTO Groups(Name,Description) VALUES
                 (@name, @desc); SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)"
      var result = await _connection.QueryAsync<int>(q, 
                                          new { @name="some name", @desc="some desc"});
      return result.Single();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to create by hand the insert query, you can use `Dapper.Contrib` [github](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.Contrib/) which helps you to manage CRUD operations.

Using Dapper.Contrib you can do something like:

```
 public async Task<int> AddNewGroup(Group entity)
 {
        using (_connection)
        {
             _connection.Open();
             var id = await _connection.InsertAsync(entity);
         }
 }
```

Comment: Do you know a solution when identity column is GUID, not an auto-increment int?

Comment: Dapper.Contrib seems that has only Insert methods that returns int or long, but if you want to get the Guid as the insert result you can create your own Insert method by using _connection.QueryFirstAsync<T>(rawSql) where rawSql is your insert statement with Output. Eg. rawSql= "insert into users (id, username, firstname, lastname) OUTPUT Inserted.Id values(newid(), 'rajiv','raj','iv');" . You can also use OUTPUT to get the whole inserted row.

Comment: Hi @Rajiv, why not generate the guid in you code function and post it with the rest and save "round trip"? guid being globally unique is ideal in this scenario

Answer (score 3):

If you're using SQL Azure / SQL Server, you need to return the inserted value from the query using something like

```
INSERT INTO groups OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES (...)
```

and then instead using `ExecuteAsync` use `ExecuteScalarAsync`

Reference to the OUTPUT clause here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yes. Remark: OUTPUT inserted.id, where id is a field name of your field mapped to key - OUTPUT inserted.keyfieldname

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        string sql = @"INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country) 
        Values (@CustomerName, @ContactName, @Address, @City, @PostalCode, @Country);
        SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            Customer c = new Customer("Brian Adams", "Brian", "12 Jones Place", "New York", "NY12", "CA");
                            
            var id = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<int>(sql, c);
            
            Console.WriteLine("The Customer ID is " + id);
            sql = "Select * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CustomerID = @ID";
            
            var rc = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<Customer>(sql, new{ @ID = id });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-quality answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the RETURNING id in the insert statement. This is using C# and dapper.

```
private readonly NpgsqlConnection _connection = new NpgsqlConnection();

var sqlInsert = $""""
            INSERT INTO tabel_name (column_name)
            VALUES ('value')
            RETURNING id;
            """";

 var id = await _connection.ExecuteScalarAsync(sqlInsert);
```

And if you want to determine the key type coming back you can use:

```
var id = await _connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(sqlInsert);
```

Where you specify the type in the <> brackets. If you do not specify, it will return the object type.

Comment: Thats the only working way atm.

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" way that I took is (Showing repository method using Guid Id to return):

```
public async Task<Guid> CreateClient(ClientEntity clientModel)
    {
        const string sql = @"
        INSERT INTO dbo.Clients
            (
                ClientCode,
                Name,
                IsActive
            )
        OUTPUT Inserted.ClientId
        VALUES
            (
                @ClientCode,
                @Name,
                @IsActive
            )";

        using var dbConnection = await _databaseProvider.GetConnection();

        var result = await dbConnection.ExecuteScalarAsync(sql, new
        {
            ClientCode = clientModel.Code,
            Name = clientModel.Name,
            IsActive = clientModel.IsActive
        });

        if (result != null)
        {
            return Guid.Parse(result.ToString());
        }
        else {
            return Guid.Empty;
        }
    }
```