# How do I get back the key for a newly inserted record using Dapper.Contrib?

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-contrib

I have code like this:

```
db.Insert(myObject);
```

The key for the type `myObject` is of type `System.Guid` which is auto generated by RDBMS.

I then want to insert child objects that will use that key to relate to their parents.

```
foreach(var child in myObject.ChildObjects) {
   child.ParentId = parentIdThatISomehowSaved; //this is what I don't know how to do
   db.Insert(child);
}
```

I am assigning a new `Guid` to the record via SQL Server when the insert occurs.

What is the best way to get the Id of the new record so I can populate it as a foreign key on child objects? The `Dapper.Contrib.Extensions.Insert` method returns a `long`, so is there a way to make this work with a `Guid`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE: 02-May-2022**

From [source code](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper.Contrib/blob/cf24f6bdc577b1e071c3764ddfb2cf3382531405/src/Dapper.Contrib/SqlMapperExtensions.cs#L312), it appears that this feature is now implemented. **I have not tested it though.**
It appears that `Insert<T>` method will *return* (it will NOT map to entity property) newly generated numeric ID (return type of method is `long`) if only single entity is being inserted. If list of entities are being inserted, it will return number of rows inserted.

I am not sure **how will this work with `GUID` IDs**.

Following is the code-comment:

> ```
> /// Inserts an entity into table "Ts" and returns identity id or number of inserted rows if inserting a list.  
> ...  
> ...  
> /// <returns>Identity of inserted entity, or number of inserted rows if inserting a list</returns>
> ```

Also, observe the [code](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper.Contrib/blob/cf24f6bdc577b1e071c3764ddfb2cf3382531405/src/Dapper.Contrib/SqlMapperExtensions.cs#L382) that inserts single entity and should return newly generated ID as per code-comment above:

> ```
> if (!isList)    //single entity
> {
>     returnVal = adapter.Insert(connection, transaction, commandTimeout, name, sbColumnList.ToString(),
>     sbParameterList.ToString(), keyProperties, entityToInsert);
> }
> else
> {
>     //insert list of entities
>     var cmd = $"insert into {name} ({sbColumnList}) values ({sbParameterList})";
>     returnVal = connection.Execute(cmd, entityToInsert, transaction, commandTimeout);
> }
> ```

---

**Original Answer:**

The [`Insert`](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper.Contrib#insert-methods) method of Dapper Contrib does not return the newly generated ID. This is because Contrib is built over Dapper which neither map the newly generated ID to the entity *by default* nor does it returns it. But there are ways to *return* the newly generated ID using Dapper. Those are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37391883/5779732), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270264/5779732) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50650985/5779732).

<sub>Dapper Extensions (other query generator for Dapper) support this by default. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56232448/5779732) answer for more details.</sub>

One way is to bypass the Contrib and use Dapper; use any of the way explained in links to get the newly generated ID (`OUTPUT` parameter or `@@IDENTITY` etc.).

Other way to do this with Contrib is to get the newly generated ID by separately calling **Dapper** (as mentioned in links; `@@IDENTITY`) immediately after a call to `Insert`.

Third way is to explicitly assign the ID instead of automatically generating it. You can use [`[ExplicitKey]`](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper.Contrib#features) attribute to achieve this. You also need to change your database accordingly.

> `[Key]` should be used for database-generated keys (e.g. autoincrement columns), while `[ExplicitKey]` should be used for explicit keys generated in code.

More aggressive solution is to modify the Contrib code to make `Insert` return newly generated ID.

By the way, I found an [issue](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper.Contrib/issues/58) similar to your problem; see if that helps you.